# Creating a database and tables in MySQL using a JDBC application

Tags: java, mysql, database

I've created a program in Java for a school project. I created the database and tables using MySQL Workbench, but now I need my program to work on other computers and therefore I need it to check if the database and tables exist, and if not create them on its own.

This is the relevant code in my driver class as it stands:

```
private static Connection conn;

static
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException exc)
    {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oops! Something seems to have gone wrong!\n\n" + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public static Connection getMySQLConnection() throws SQLException
{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tournament_manager", "studentCouncil", "****");
    return conn;
}
```

As above, the database I would like to create, if it does not exist, is to be called "tournament_manager". The tables to be created with the database are as follows:

**Table 1 Name: password**

Column 1: passwordID
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO

Column 2: password
*Type:* varchar(20)
*Nullable:* YES
*Character Set:* latin1

**Table 2 Name: tournaments**

Column 1: tournamentID
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO
*Extra:* auto_increment

Column 2: tournamentName
*Type:* varchar(20)
*Nullable:* NO
*Character Set:* latin1

Column 3: date
*Type:* date
*Nullable:* NO

Column 4: startTime
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO

Column 5: matchDuration
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO

Column 6: breakDuration
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO

Column 7: numTeams
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO

Column 8: numVenues
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO

**Table 3 Name: teams**

Column 1: teamID
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO
*Extra:* auto_increment

Column 2: teamName
*Type:* varchar(20)
*Nullable:* NO
*Character Set:* latin1

Column 3: points
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO

Column 4: tournaments_tournamentID
*Type:* int(11)
*Nullable:* NO

I am new to stack overflow, so I may have not included all the relevant information or included irrelevant information. In the case that I haven't included relevant details, please ask.

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: But what's the problem?

Comment: You can get a `DatabaseMetaData` object from your `Connection` object via `getMetaData()`. Once you have that object, you can query it for existing tables and create them using standard SQL, if they are not there using your `Connection` object.

Comment: You can do it, but I'd consider it a bad design to be creating tables in Java.  Usually applications create a schema before the app runs and then perform CRUD operations with Java.  You're making that classic student/beginner mistake: Mingling database and UI code in one class.  There's no separation of concerns there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create tables, you should use the "CREATE TABLE" SQL syntax. This can be done on the database management program but also in JDBC.

```
  stmt = conn.createStatement();

  String sql = "CREATE TABLE password" +
               "(passwordId INTEGER not NULL, " +
               " password VARCHAR(20), " + 
               " PRIMARY KEY ( passwordId ))"; 

  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually *you can do it* with Hibernate JPA.

**Create a Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id
  @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
  private String firstName
  @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
  private String lastName
}
```

**Define hibernate auto creation**

in applicationContext.xml (spring-servlet.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml) add that:

```
         <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            // That property create tables and key options.
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        </properties>
```

**Start Server**

When you start server hibernate will create your tables or update your columns.

Comment: Just because you can do it with hibernate, doesn't mean you need to use an additional library to accomplish it and where in the question does it mention spring servlet?

Comment: He wants to create tables in Java. Hibernate auto is a tool for it. Spring-servlet is a etc. case. Which xml he has he can use it.

Comment: I'm saying the code the question provided uses DriverManager and here you are promoting an alternative method. While it may attempt to answer, it does not directly solve the problem addressed in the question. If you could explain what hibernate is and why it should be used with a runnable example, maybe your answer will be accepted.